# How to access prefab's button text child?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying something and I have a button in my prefab. I want to bind the texts in the text of the button to the variable. For example, on my button, the price of the product is written. I'm changing the price somewhere in the game, but I cannot change the text of the price in the button. How can I get the text of the button in the prefab?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of ways you can achieve this. I'll be explaining 1 solution which you can use (easiest, assuming button is static).

**Solution:**

Button is static in scene, i.e. you are not instantiating the button dynamically.

In the script which deals with changing the price (where price is stored in variable), make another variable:

```
public Button thisButton;
```

In the Inspector, you'll see this variable exposed now. You can drag and drop button from your scene to this thisButton variable in Inspector.

Now wherever you need to update the text, you can update the text in this way

```
public void UpdateButtonText(string text)
{
  thisButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = text;
}
```

Now you can call the function "UpdateButtonText(string)" with updated price that you need to update on the button.

Let me know if you're dynamically instantiating the button at runtime, I'll explain another solution then.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I can't drag it from Inspector because my button is inside Prefab. Is there a way to reach the button in Prefab with a script? Or do I need to detach the button from Prefab?